# xp mode in windows7 won't work

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp-mode

i have downloaded and installed the xp mode file in windows7 pro. it installs ok but there is no executable and no shortcuts to start it, i have gone into the bios and turned on virtulisation but i can't find how to start the program

Comment: Same problem.  Install went fine, but only appears in the uninstall control panel.  No sign of it in the menus (not in any of the places suggested in the answers below).

Answer (score 1):

Look under Virtual Windows XP or Virtual Computers in your Start menu.

Comment: Here its "Windows Virtual PC", which will either open a folder view of all the machines, or, once you've used XP Mode should be on the recent list for Windows Virtual PC.

Answer (score 0):

Once installed XP mode can be found in the Start Menu > All Programs > Windows Virtual PC > Windows XP Mode or you can search for 'XP Mode' in the Start Menu's search box.

Answer (score 0):

Aha.  There's a Windows update (or 2 depending on your exact revision).  Without those, XP Mode will install, but NOT be accessible!  Install those updates and it appears on the menu!